# What are the required Roles to remediate Azure Defender and Security Center vulnerability assessment?

Tags: azure, azure-defender

What are the roles I need to request to remediate all vulnerability assessment recommendation in Azure?

Comment: Your question in its current form is no fit for SO. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: this information is all pretty well documented, like in [Permissions in Azure Security Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-permissions)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [“What topics can I ask about here?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [“What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read (the Stack Overflow question checklist)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922]. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Defender (or in it's new new - Microsoft Defender for Cloud) doesn't have an API to remediate vulnerabilities found by a vulnerability assessment solution.
Each vulnerability description also contains the actions you should take to remediate the vulnerability, usually by logging into the vulnerable machine (SSH / RDP) and perform the described actions.